# rxplot is not plotting as it is supposed to be

Tags: ros, rxplot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've tried to utilize *rxplot* for visualizing 2 variable values, however, one of them is not plotting. It seems to be disappeared. No color at all. Another one is just plotting out of the box. I run the command like below, for instance:

```
rxplot /pose_1/pose/position/x, /pose_2/pose/position/x
```

One could assume that problematic variable value is because of its values is always zero. But, this is not my case.

What could be the culprit or there is any bug with the *rxplot*?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12530/rxplot-is-not-plotting-as-it-is-supposed-to-be/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-05**:
Yes, it is publsihed, and I even can "rostopic echo /topic" there, and see its values.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-05**:
Have you confirmed that the message is being properly published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, the problem is resolved. The culprit is because of the variable is having a constant timestamp. And now I know, it is time-dependent.

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2